# Having difficulty when finding minima and maxima of function with ln.

Tags: calculus

My online homework reads:

Let
$f(x) = 4 \ln(10x)-4x$, $x>0$

Find critical point(s).

For this problem would I have to use the product or chain rule?

In addition, when setting the simplified function equal to $0$, would I get rid of $\ln$ on one side by using the exponential of both sides?

Thank you!

Comment: What is a "critical point"?

Comment: A critical point are points for which when $f'(x) = 0$.
$$ $$
*Hint:* $\ln(10x) = \ln 10 + \ln x$. What is the derivative of $\ln x$? What's the derivative of $-4x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $-4x$ with respect to $x$ is $-4$; the derivative of $\log(10x)$ with respect to $x$ is taken via the chain rule: derivative of $\log(x)$ with respect to $x$ (which is $1/x$) evaluated at point $10x$ (which yields $1/(10x)$) is multiplied by the derivative of $10x$ with respect to $x$, which is $10$. Now the derivative of $4\log(10x)$ with respect to $x$ is just four times the derivative of $\log(10x)$ with respect to $x$ as constant factors can be carried out of the differential operator.

Combining:
$$f'(x)=4\frac{1}{10x}\times10-4=\frac{4}{x}-4.$$

Now to solve $f'(x)=0$ for $x$, add $4$ to both sides:
$$\frac{4}{x}=4;$$
divide both sides by $4$:
$$\frac{1}{x}=1;$$
multiply both sides by $x$:
$$x=1.$$

Therefore $1$ is a critical point of $f$.
Please notice that $0$ is also a critical point, as it yields an infinite numerical value of $f'$.

Comment: Since $0$ is not in the domain of $f,$ $0$ is not a critical point. In fact, the statement that $f'$ has an infinite numerical value at $x=0$ is also false, for the same reason.

Comment: @Dave, a domain of a function is a part of function's definition. As it is not given explicitly, I am free to assume the most general case with $f(0)=-\infty$.

Comment: Given the context (elementary calculus, not real or complex analysis), I suspect the functions involved are intended to be real valued, not extended real valued.